# Any way to have a Meteor Autoform input outside of form tag?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I have an `autoForm` but I need to break it up into separate parts visually. The `afFieldArray` at the bottom of my code cannot stand just on its own - it needs to be wrapped inside of `{{#autoForm}}`, but doing so would screw up my page layout. I want them all to use the same schema and to be submitted and validated all as a single form's contents.

```
{{#autoForm validation="keyup" schema=orderFormSchema id="order-submission-form" type="insert"}}

    <div class="col-md-12">
      {{> afQuickField name="propertyInfo.sqft" class="form-control"}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      {{> afQuickField name="propertyInfo.zipcode" class="form-control"}}
    </div>

{{/autoForm}}

/** Lots of other HTML junk that prevents this afFieldArray from 
being nested inside of the autoForm helpers**/

{{> afArrayField template="bootstrap3_custom" name="discountsApplied" class="form-control"}}
```

Any ideas how this could be accomplished?

Comment: I would just stick that html code inside the autoform tags. I don't think there's a way to do what you want and it looks like a mess anyway. You can use custom autoform templates if you need and that helps things..

Comment: It doesn't  need to look like a mess if it's a long form and you want to break up components for an easier user experience. I really don't understand why form inputs EVER have to be nested inside of form tags - it should be enough to just assign a class to each input field, wherever they are, and have a function that reads all the input values of a certain class and bundles and validates it all in one shot. HTML is for semantics and physical structure, not for data-gathering. At least allow multiple form tags in the HTML, each with the same form name so you know which inputs go with what form.

Comment: I don't know why the html you're putting into the code is bothered by the fact that it's surrounded by a form tag